How to pipe processed output of youtube-dl-exec to frontend with nodejs
I am trying to pipe the output of youtube-dl-exec to the front end but I cant seem to figure  out how.
export default async function convertAndDownload(req: Request, res: Response) {
  try {
    const { video, meta, filename } = req.body;

    res.header("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename="${filename}"`);
    const videoUrl = `https://youtube.com/watch?v=${video.id}`;

    const cmd = youtubedl.exec(videoUrl, {
      extractAudio: true,
      audioFormat: "mp3",
      audioQuality: "10",
      output: "-",
      postprocessorArgs: [`ffmpeg: -metadata title="${meta.title}"`],
      addHeader: ["referer:youtube.com", "user-agent:googlebot"],
    });

    cmd.stdout.pipe(res, { end: true });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      msg: "There was an error during processing.",
    });
  }
}

This actually works but the output is not mp3 it is webm so I'm assuming I'm just getting the stream and not the processed file or just a piece of the stream maybe. If I remove the pipe and just directly download it to the filesystem via youtubedl like:
const cmd = youtubedl.exec(videoUrl, {
  extractAudio: true,
  audioFormat: "mp3",
  audioQuality: "10",
  output: "output.mp3",
  postprocessorArgs: [`ffmpeg: -metadata title="${meta.title}"`],
  addHeader: ["referer:youtube.com", "user-agent:googlebot"],
});

This works fine but it obviously just writes the file to the filesystem and I need to send it to the front end. youtubedl returns a promise so I figured I would try waiting for the output:
const cmd = youtubedl.exec(videoUrl, {
  extractAudio: true,
  audioFormat: "mp3",
  audioQuality: "10",
  output: "-",
  postprocessorArgs: [`ffmpeg: -metadata title="${meta.title}"`],
  addHeader: ["referer:youtube.com", "user-agent:googlebot"],
}).then((output) => {
    output.stdout.pipe(res, { end: true }); 
});

This results in TypeError: output.stdout.pipe is not a function. So then I tried to remove exec and just write the output directly into res:
const cmd = youtubedl(videoUrl, {
  extractAudio: true,
  audioFormat: "mp3",
  audioQuality: "10",
  output: "-",
  postprocessorArgs: [`ffmpeg: -metadata title="${meta.title}"`],
  addHeader: ["referer:youtube.com", "user-agent:googlebot"],
}).then((output) => {
  console.log(output)
  res.write(output);
  res.end(); 
});

This just sends a corrupt file to the client. I tried logging the output and that logs a bunch of unreadable characters so I can only assume its a file output of some sort but I have no way of knowing what it actually is and when I download it the file is way bigger than it should be so idk.
I also tried just using the child process and piping it that way but it results in a pretty large file that also isn't a playable mp3:
const cmd = youtubedl.exec(videoUrl, {
  extractAudio: true,
  audioFormat: "mp3",
  audioQuality: "10",
  output: "-",
  postprocessorArgs: [`ffmpeg: -metadata title="${meta.title}"`],
  addHeader: ["referer:youtube.com", "user-agent:googlebot"],
});

cmd.stdout.pipe(res);

cmd.stdout.on("data", (data: any) => {
  console.log("writing data");
  res.write(data);
});

cmd.stdout.on("close", () => {
  console.log("closed");
  res.end(); // End the response
});

Needless to say I'm stumped. Help would be appreciated I'm sure I'm missing something simple but not sure what. Thanks
